# How can i edit in php with sql

Tags: php, html, mysql, edit

My Code -

```
<?php
 //Retrieves data from MySQL 
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data


 Echo "<img src=http://www.mywebsite.com/upload/".$info['video'] ."> <br>";  //This is the name of my Video URL in MySQL
 Echo "<b>Video</b> ".$info['Video'] . "<br> ";        //This is the name of my Video Name in MySQL
 Echo "<b>Author</b> ".$info['Author'] . "<br> ";        //This is the name of my USER in MySQL
 Echo "<b>Category</b> ".$info['category'] . "<br> ";    //This is the name of Video Category in MySQL
 Echo "<b>Description</b> ".$info['Description'] . "<hr>";       //This is the name of Description in MySQL
 }
 ?>
```

As raw output the details are coming in List like this -

```
Image1
Video name1
Author name1
Category1
Description1

<hr>

Image2
Video name2
Author name2
Category2
Description2
```

Now want to Make put `<div>` Tags and  Tags in between the Image, Author, Video Name

How can i put ? Cuz when i edit "`<br>`" and insert "`<div class="thumb"></div><br>`"

> It shows error ! - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/servin/public_html/upload/view.php on line 14

How can i edit mysql php code so that i can add the html codes + the All details must also shows like this

Comment: `It shows error !` What error?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/servin/public_html/upload/view.php on line 14

Comment: it shows a syntax error because he's doing class="thumb" inside " on the echo. :) `echo "<div class=\"thumb\">".$info['Description']."</div><br />";`

Comment: Please write an example of the HTML code you are trying to generate, as this is not very clear. You can also post the PHP code that "shows error" (along with the error :).

Comment: read up on string escaping

Comment: @Dave Can you please Explain the solution little more i think you are saying the right process

Comment: I do explain it! you're using double quotes inside double quotes which you cannot do you need to escape the quotes around the class so they don't cause you to drop out of the echo statement and back into php

Comment: Thanks Dave i got it use ' inplace of "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant use double quotes by this `<div class="thumb">`  you should use it like that `<div class='thumb'>` with single quote .because you already using it with echo , try this :

```
    <?php
   //Retrieves data from MySQL 
  $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
 //Puts it into an array 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 

 //Outputs the image and other data


  echo "<div class='thumb'><img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/upload/".$info['video'] ." ' /> </div><br>";  //This is the name of my Video URL in MySQL
  echo "<div class='thumb'><b>Video</b> ".$info['Video'] . "<br /> ";        //This is   the name of my Video Name in MySQL
  echo "<div class='thumb'><b>Author</b> ".$info['Author'] . "<br /> ";        //This is the name of my USER in MySQL
  echo "<div class='thumb'><b>Category</b> ".$info['category'] . "<br /> ";    //This is the name of Video Category in MySQL
  echo "<div class='thumb'><b>Description</b> ".$info['Description'] . "<hr>";         //This is the name of Description in MySQL
 }
 ?>
```

**EDIT:** if you want use html here better way

```
   <?php
   //Retrieves data from MySQL 
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error()); 
   //Puts it into an array 
   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
   { 

   //Outputs the image and other data
   ?>

   <div class='thumb'><img src='http://www.mywebsite.com/upload/<?php echo $info['video']; ?> ' /> </div><br /> 
   <div class='thumb'><b>Video</b><?php echo $info['Video'] ;?><br />         
   <div class='thumb'><b>Author</b><?php echo $info['Author'] ;?><br />       
   <div class='thumb'><b>Category</b><?php echo $info['category'] ; ?><br />   
   <div class='thumb'><b>Description</b><?php echo $info['Description'] ; ?><hr />      
  <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: Am i the only one disgusted by singlequotes in html.. Why not the other way around? Or even better, why not use DOM or similar to output HTML ?

Comment: I tend to use `echo '.....<img src="">';` but please, enclose the img src url.. it hurts in my eyes

Comment: i just use \" instead :) single quotes should not be in html tbh